# How can I tell my manager that I need short-term leave to take care of my pregnant wife?

Tags: management

My wife is pregnant and she has not been doing well for the past few days. She needs personal care (this is also her doctor’s advice). To take care of her, I need at least two weeks of leave. How can I convey to my manager that I need short-term leave for two weeks?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to say exactly what you've said here? Do you have reason to believe a completely truthful request would be denied, or held against you later? Please edit some more background into your question. For example, the time-off policy of your company, the size of the company, and the country where you work, along with your thoughts about how your manager will react to a straight-ahead request.

Comment: @KateGregory I agree. What is stopping you from saying exactly this? This sounds like a reasonable request and most places offer 2 weeks vacation. You could ask about it.

Comment: What country do you live in too? This can make a significant impact. Many countries have governmental policies about this.

Answer (score 15):

You go to your manager and you say,

> My wife is pregnant. She has not been doing well for the past few days. Her doctor advises that she needs personal care. I will need at least two weeks of leave to take care of her.

This is not complicated.

Comment: If it is in the United States, it is very possible that this has already occurred and boss said no. Which he is fully allowed to say. We need more feedback from OP.

Comment: @user2989297 In the US, the boss is not allowed to say no. The FMLA mandates 12 weeks of unpaid leave over the course of a year to care for sick family members, assuming a certain period of experience with the company and size of the company.